# Crear un botón para abrir un archivo de una ruta específica

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdf

Pido su ayuda a la comunidad de stackoverflow para resolver esto: Tengo una tabla
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hm15.png
En ella al lado voy a crear una columna Acciones y cada fila tendrá un botón "Ver", este botón debe abrir un archivo.pdf específico el que le corresponda, es decir al presionar el botón "Ver" de cualquier fila debe traerme un archivo.pdf estos ya están generados previamente y guardados en una carpeta
https://i.stack.imgur.com/maP6A.png
En definitiva el botón de cualquier fila de la tabla debe abrir otra pestaña con el contenido del archivo.pdf. Lo que pretendía hacer es mediante un if si el codigo de una fila es igual al nombre de un archivo entonces mostrar o traer dicho archivo... pero no se como plasmarlo en PHP. Porfavor necesito de vuestra ayuda y sus consejos. GRacias , por su colaboración os dejaré el nombre de 2 apps para mejorar grandemente el sonido de su teléfono.

Códigos de la tabla:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
<th>N° Boleta</th>
<th>Fecha y Hora</th>
<th>Totales (S/)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php   require "../conexion.php";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nofactura, fecha,codcliente, totalfactura, estado FROM factura ORDER BY nofactura DESC");
mysqli_close($conexion);
$cli = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($cli > 0) {
while ($dato = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo 'N' . $dato['nofactura']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $dato['fecha']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $dato['totalfactura']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }
} ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

debes agregar una nueva columna a la cual le meteras un boton con un evento en javascript con la direccion de tu documento pdf

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
<th>N° Boleta</th>
<th>Fecha y Hora</th>
<th>Totales (S/)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php   require "../conexion.php";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nofactura, fecha,codcliente, totalfactura, estado FROM factura ORDER BY nofactura DESC");
mysqli_close($conexion);
$cli = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($cli > 0) {
while ($dato = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo 'N' . $dato['nofactura']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $dato['fecha']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $dato['totalfactura']; ?></td>
<td><button onclick="javascript:location.href='Dirección donde está guardado el archivo/<?php echo($dato['documento']) ? 
>'">archivoPdf</button>
</tr>
<?php }
} ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Nota: los archivos PDF deben de estar dentro de la carpeta donde está guardada tu página web si es con wamp debe de ir dentro de la carpeta www

Comment: Tras la prueba.. No me ha funcionado